# HashSet equals, hashCode are overriden, styl have duplicates

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, hashset

```
 public class DateObj extends Date implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private String fName;
    private String sName;
    private String days;
    private String country;
    private boolean fitIn;


    public DateObj(String id,String fName, String sName, String country, String days) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.sName = sName;
        this.days = days;
        this.country = country;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        DateObj dateObj = (DateObj) obj;
        System.out.println("method Call");


        return getfName().equals(dateObj.getfName());
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getsName() {
        return sName;
    }

    public void setsName(String sName) {
        this.sName = sName;
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(String days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return fName;
    }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return fName.hashCode();
}
```

}

==========================================================================================

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class DataSaveTo {

    private ArrayList<DateObj> listData = new ArrayList<DateObj>();
    File file = new File("data3.csv");
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        DataSaveTo dataExperiment = new DataSaveTo();
        dataExperiment.go();


    }

    public void go() {



        loadData();

        TreeSet<DateObj> data = new TreeSet<DateObj>();
        data.addAll(listData);
    //  ObjComparInt comparId = new ObjComparInt();
    //  ObjectComparable comparObj = new ObjectComparable();
    //  Collections.sort(listData, comparId);
        saveData();
    //  System.out.println(listData);


    }



    public void saveData() {

        try {
            File file = new File("dataNoDupl.csv");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            for(DateObj obj : listData){
                bw.write(obj.getId()+";"+obj.getfName()+";"+obj.getsName()+";"+obj.getCountry()+";"+obj.getDays()+"\n ");
            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception in save Data method:  "+ e);

        }

    }

    public  void loadData() {
        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(file);
            String s = null;
            String[] tokens;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                tokens = s.split(",");
                createDateObj(tokens);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in LoadData method"+e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in LoadData method 2nd catch"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    private void createDateObj(String[] tokens) {

        DateObj obj = new DateObj(tokens[4],tokens[0],tokens[2],tokens[3],tokens[1]);
        listData.add(obj);
        System.out.println(obj.hashCode()+"--"+obj.getfName()+"--"+obj.getsName());

    }



    //  Name comparator
    public class ObjectComparable implements Comparator<DateObj>{
        @Override
        public int compare(DateObj obj, DateObj obj1) {
            return obj.getfName().compareTo(obj1.getfName());

        }
    }

        // ID comparator
    public class ObjComparInt implements Comparator<DateObj>{
        @Override   
        public int compare(DateObj ob, DateObj ob1){
            return Integer.parseInt(ob.getId()) - Integer.parseInt(ob1.getId());
            }
        }


    }
```

I want HashSet to call equal method, because of overriden hashCode. And after equals compare,I want to remove duplicates in mine Collection I am passing into the hashSet.

```
HashSet<DateObj> data = new HashSet<DateObj>();
    data.addAll(listData);
```

In console it prints me out, true (because of sys.out in equals method) but it does not do anything. I styl have duplicates.

Comment: Your equals method only uses the fName field, yet hashCode uses both fName and sName. Shouldn't your equals method also be overridden to compare both fName and sName??

Comment: Please read about the "contract" between hashcode and equals. they must be equivalent!! You could also try to re-generate hashCode and equals in your IDE, and go from there.

Comment: Edit your question, and add a few examples where you run into problems (and your updated code). Also, please avoid abbreviations - meth != method.

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely the result you are expecting, and what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With having same `fName` does not get same hash Value. As you consider `sName` also while generating hash code.

When you are putting the objects into your `HashSet`, hash code is generated and your hash code implementation generates hash code according to your `fName` and `sName`. On the other hand you are matching only `fName` in your equal method and get `true` printed!

First Define when you want to consider your objects same. Use those criteria to match in `equals` method and also consider them in `hashCode` method also. ***Because if two objects are equal, their hash code must to be equal***!

Comment: Yes wasn't it expected? as you are saying in your equls method to consider the objects same having same `fName`!

Comment: @user1984327 No matter what trick you have planned, your hashcode implementation is wrong. If you have two objects which are equal according to the equals method, the hashcode method **must** be the same for those objects, or your hashcode implementation is broken. And if you have for example "Bob Smith" and "Bob Johnson", they are equal, but have different hashcodes in your example, which is **wrong**.

Comment: Well, I am afraid, in that case you have to write your own `HashSet` implementation then!

Comment: ok, sory, tell me pls what should i change in  code. I can't find why i styl have duplicates

Answer (score 0):

The Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) of `hashCode()` states that:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

Your implementation is breaking this rule, and you need to change either the implementation of [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) or [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to fulfill it.

You probably want to update `equals()`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof DateObj)) {
        return false;
    }
    DateObj dateObj = (DateObj) obj;
    return getfName().equals(dateObj.getfName()) && getsName().equals(dateObj.getsName());
}
```

Comment: the implementation doesn't need to make sense, and it can always rely on the specification. Actually a quick look shows that `HashSet`s uses a `HashMap` to persist its elements as keys and the `HashMap.put()` method requires two keys to have the same hash (one of the conditions) in order to consider them equal.